# Processing XML with Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: xml, hadoop, xml-parsing, mapreduce

I want to load and parse some petabytes of XML data. After doing lot of research on how to process XML in hadoop I have come to know that XML has to be processed as whole file in Map Reduce.

If i feed whole XML as single input split to my Map Reduce then It will not be utilizing hadoop's distributed and parallel processing feature as only one Mapper will be doing processing.

Is that I correctly understood? How to overcome this problem?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use Mahout's [XMLInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/66f164057e322d2e63ea02c35c9e30c3969e80b1/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.java). XMLInputFormat takes care of figuring out the record boundaries with in your XML input files using the specified start and end tags.

You could use this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice) as reference on how to use  XMLInputFormat to parse your XML files.

Comment: my doubt is if i'm putting XMLs in hadoop will it be distributed? if yes then how it will be processed ?

Comment: Yes, putting XML's files in hadoop will be distributed based on the block size. Based on the block size XML files will be split and distributed among DataNode's. While processing using MapReduce you have to take care of figuring out the [record boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562146/record-reader-and-record-boundaries) to make sure you are processing all of the XML record properly even if the record is split across multiple HDFS blocks, for that you can use Mahout's XMLInputFormat.

Comment: sorry just want to confirm..you mean multiple mappers will be launched to parse the XML ?

Comment: Yes. Multiple mappers will be launched based on your input split's.

Comment: currently I'm running a MapReduce code for parsing XML its creating 23 part files in output directory, to avoid this i will have to use XmlInputFormat instead of TextInputFormat correct? if I'm using XmlInput format then whole XML will be in one input split or it will have multiple input split and multiple mappers too

Comment: `XmlInputFormat` will have multiple input split's based on your provided start and end tags, hence you'll have mappers processing each input split.

Comment: hey thanks..is there any other way or tool to ingest XML in hadoop ?

Comment: @Ashrith I read the article. And then I read a little about Mahout. So it looks like we will need to install Mahout. So in short we are not using hadoop but using Mahout. Is my understanding correct ? Or is there way to simply refer Mahout jars in hadoop ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single block of XML data that is a petabyte in size, you have a problem. More likely you have millions or billions of individual XML records. If that is the case, you have a rather straightforward approach: create millions of XML files that have a size that is roughly the same (a little smaller) than the block size of your HDFS system. Then write a set of MapReduce jobs where the first mapper extracts the XML data and outputs whatever (name,value) pairs are useful, and the reducer collects all of the different (name) pairs from the various XML files that require correlation.

If the XML dataset is changing over time you may wish to look at support for streaming datasets.